# Kafka P2P Header based routing

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a requirement to send an event to multiple systems based on their system code. Destination system can grow in future and they should be able to subscribe only to the interested events. Its a security mandate, so as a producer we need to ensure this.
We could use RabbitMQ header exchange and use multiple shovel configurations to the different queues in different vhost or cluster. But I am looking for a similar pattern with  Kafka.
If we maintain different topic and authorise the consumer to their corresponding topic, it can grow in future, so as a producer I need to do the topic routing logic and the number of topics will grow.

The other option is to use AWS SNS and subscribe multiple SQS queues. Based on filter policies the message can be routed.

Could anyone think of a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> send an event to multiple systems based on their system code

Using Kafka Streams API, you can use [branching](https://kafka.apache.org/31/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations) to route data to different topics based on Predicate logic

Once data is in their respective topics, "multiple systems" can consume them